# How to save longitude and latitude from the marker i set on the map

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps-markers

I know how to set location from coordinates and when the maps activity starts it will jump to those coordinates but i want the user to be able to set a marker on the map and save the coordinates into some variables but i have no idea how to do that. Kindly point me in the right direction.

```
  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(sydney)
                .title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
```

Added some pics for full view of my code. I am sorry i m really new into this maps stuff. Every comment will help me learn more about this.

[image: code1]

[image: code2]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a global variable for your activity

```
private LatLng myLatLng;
```

Next, you need to set up a marker drag listener for your map

```
map.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
                    
                }

                @Override
                public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {

                     myLatLng = marker.getPosition();

                }
});
```

If you want to save the marker as a variable...

```
private Marker myMarker;
private LatLng myLatLng;


myMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                   .position(sydney)
                   .title("Marker in Sydney"));

myLatLng = myMarker.getPosition();
```

Comment: okay but what exactly should i do to save the location at the marker placed by the person who is selecting the location

Comment: Not sure how you want to save it. As a global variable? As a settings file?

Comment: User will click on button and map will open than user will drag marker around and click another button to save the location he selected with the marker. Thus saving longitude and latitude in some variables

Comment: I have edited my answer to fit your needs. Make sure after adding the marker, it is set to be draggable.

Comment: Hello i m almost Done with this thing. One last thing i need to know is how can i get lng and lat in different variables instead of mylatlng. When i put myLatLng in firebase it makes object inside and object and that is causing some problems

Comment: Correct, Firebase can not save object type LatLng, so you will need to write your own logic that understands how to write and read LatLngs using a string format. String.valueOf(myMarker.getPosition().latitude + "," + String.valueOf(myMarker.getPosition().longitude); That string can then be saved to firebase. When reading the value from firebase, you will need to split the string using the comma as the delimiter thus getting the lat and lng values. These values will be strings, so you need to convert from string to double.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your last line with

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 15));
```

Answer (score 0):

**First** add marker on map

```
private void setUpMap()
    {
        .......
        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

        myMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title("My Spot")
                    .snippet("This is my spot!")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
        ......
    }
```

**then** use this code to get marker location

```
  @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(
                MainActivity.this,
                "Lat " + map.getMyLocation().getLatitude() + " "
                        + "Long " + map.getMyLocation().getLongitude(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println("yalla b2a "
                + map.getMyLocation().getLatitude());
    }
```